# New line in text inside div

Tags: html, css

In a textarea, there are new lines using for example `&#013;`, but how can I do this to a div element without using htmll (plain text like \n) ?

Comment: `\n` || `\r` || `"\n"` || `"\r"`

Comment: It doesn't work inside a div element.

Comment: Add `white-space: pre;` CSS rule.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use CSS to force HTML to recognize new lines as line breaks.

Just set the `white-space` property to `pre`:

```
div {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Dph8S/)

Comment: Which browsers support this.

Comment: All of them, all the way back to IE6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Excellent fix for when taking text value from a text-area and applying to a div. Extra credit: use pre-wrap to allow word-break property work as needed (IE8+)

Comment: I had to use white-space: pre-wrap to make it work properly on Chrome

Comment: Or you can use `pre-wrap` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: This is. what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: pre-wrap and break-spaces also worked for me. For white-space