# How do I create multiline text with the dojo createText() method?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using the dojo createText function to programmatically create a text object in Javascript.  This functionality has been working well except for newline characters within the string.  I would like for this functionality to be able to handle multiline text as well as single line text.  For example:

```
var content = “Mercury\nVenus\nEarth\nMars”;
console.log(content);
surface.createText({x: 0, y: 0, text: content, align: “start”});
```

console.log shows this:
Mercury
Venus
Earth
Mars

Whereas createText draws this:
Mercury Venus Earth Mars

The behavior appears to be as if createText is replacing the newline character with a space character.  Is there a syntax to get createText to draw the text visually as console.log does for multiline content?  Or is the only option to split the string and use a separate createText for each?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the issue with dojo, but HTML. linebreaks are not recognized in HTML
you need to replace `\n` with `<br/>` or you need to force HTML to recognize it as mentioned in this post
[New line in text inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963821/new-line-in-text-inside-div)